# Search key in Mongodb document

Tags: mongodb

following is my json which i have inserted in mongodb. I need to find record where cardholders value is 200

```
 {
  "_id": "11",
  "cardholders": {
    "100": [
      {
        "message": "message1",
        "time": "timestamp"
      },
      {
        "message": "message2",
        "time": "timestamp"
      }
    ],
    "200": [
      {
        "message": "message1",
        "time": "timestamp"
      },
      {
        "message": "message2",
        "time": "timestamp"
      },
      {
        "message": "message3",
        "time": "timestamp"
      }
    ],
    "300": [
      {
        "message": "message1",
        "time": "timestamp"
      },
      {
        "message": "message2",
        "time": "timestamp"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please advice. I have following

```
 db.test3.find({"message1":{$eq:true}})
> db.test3.find({"100":{$eq:true}})
> db.test3.find({cardholders:{$eq:'100'}})
> db.test3.find({cardholders:{$eq:100}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially want to include a **[projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** argument in your find() query which matches documents containing only the projection field and the `_id` field. In this case since `"200"` is the key, you can project it and use the **[`map()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/)** cursor to get the values as follows:

```
db.test3.find(
    {}, 
    {"cardholders.200": 1}
).map(function(doc){ return doc["cardholders"]["200"]})
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "0" : [ 
        {
            "message" : "message1",
            "time" : "timestamp"
        }, 
        {
            "message" : "message2",
            "time" : "timestamp"
        }, 
        {
            "message" : "message3",
            "time" : "timestamp"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

To make querying easier, I would recommend changing your schema to change the cardholders key into an array that holds embedded documents. These embedded documents would have a key and value fields; the key field holds the previous dynamic keys and the value field holds the array values:

```
{
  "_id": "11",
  "cardholders": [
    {
        "key": "100",
        "values": [
            {
                "message": "message1",
                "time": "timestamp"
            },
            {
                "message": "message2",
                "time": "timestamp"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "200",
        "values": [
            {
                "message": "message1",
                "time": "timestamp"
            },
            {
                "message": "message2",
                "time": "timestamp"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "300",
        "values": [
            {
                "message": "message1",
                "time": "timestamp"
            },
            {
                "message": "message2",
                "time": "timestamp"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can then query the embedded documents using a combination of the **[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#equality-match-on-fields-within-an-embedded-document)** and the **[`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)** projection as follows:

```
db.test3.find(
    {"cardholders.key": "200"}, 
    { 
        "cardholders": { 
            "$elemMatch": { "key": "200" } 
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks that works, do you think that i can restructure this json in a better way and still achieve similar results with a easier search query

Comment: this works as well, taken from your answer db.test3.find(     {},      {"cardholders.200": 1} )

Comment: @Amit Absolutely, for MongoDB it's recommended to restructure your schema where you have dynamic keys as it's complex to query with such type of keys. I've updated my answer with an alternative schema approach and ways to query that which are simpler.